# POSTFIX & Wordpress : Email sent by "www-data"

Tags: wordpress, debian, postfix-mta

I setup 2 email account in my postfix, but when i try to send an email on my wordpress, it's trying to send with "www-data" address.

My wordpress use 2 email account on the same domain.

Somebody know how i can replace www-data by the email address who wordpress use ?

Thanks in advance

I try to setup postfix with canonical but it only send with only 1 address